# How do I redirect the url after a state update in a react redux application?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I have a simple react redux application using react-router-redux. I have 2 routes, one is `feed` the other `add`. The add view provides a form. On form submission an `ADD_STORY` action is dispatched and my reducer properly sets a new state with the added story. Problem is I would like to redirect at that point to the `feed` view. My current approach below is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

my deps:

```
"react": "^15.4.1",
"react-dom": "^15.4.1",
"react-redux": "^4.4.6",
"react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
"react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.4",
"redux": "^3.6.0"
```

index.js

```
//... other imports above
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { Route } from 'react-router'

import { ConnectedRouter, routerReducer, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'

// Create a history of your choosing (we're using a browser history in this case)
const history = createHistory()

// Build the middleware for intercepting and dispatching navigation actions
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history)

// Add the reducer to your store on the `router` key
// Also apply our middleware for navigating
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
)

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <HashRouter>
            <div className={styles.app}>
          <Header />
                <div>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Feed} />
                  <Route exact path="/add" component={AddStory} />
                </div>
              <Footer />
            </div>
          </HashRouter>
     </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};
```

I then at another part of my code attempt to redirect from a container component

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  console.log('ownProps', ownProps)

  return {
    submitStory: (story) => {
      dispatch(createStory({
        title: story.match(/^(.+)\n?/)[1],
        body: story
      }))
    },
    doAction: (action) => {
      switch(action) {
        case "STORY_ADDED":
          console.log('PUSHING');
          ownProps.history.push('/')
          dispatch(push('/'))
          break;
        default: 
          return null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are several issues I'm encountering. One is if I attempt `dispatch(ownProps.history.push('/')` I get an error in the middleware about the `action` being undefined. This is easy to understand since `ownProps.history.push('/')` returns undefined; though it will redirect; but only once. If I try to use the `push` that comes from `react-router-redux` I get a proper `action` object returned, but no redirect with `dispatch(push('/'))`.

As you can see I attempted to remedy the situation by calling `ownProps.history.push('/')` then dispatching with react-router-redux push so I have proper action object but this only works once as well. My component's `shouldComponentUpdate` method never triggers on the state update; even though a new state is clearly produced; adding a new story in the view I'm attempting to redirect to.

Thanks again.

Comment: which version of `react-router`?

Comment: why not just use browserHistory ? `browserHistory.push(...)` and import it like so `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';`

Comment: by deps: "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.4",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  } @AnthonyKong

Comment: @JohnRuddell I get: bundle.js:44241 ./src/containers/AddStory.js
25:19-33 "export 'browserHistory' was not found in 'react-router'

Comment: @JohnRuddell "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.4",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  }

Comment: @micahblu do you not have the package react-router? and how are you setting up your routes?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I do have react-router and I'm able to import Route without a problem. It would appear perhaps that this version of react-router  react-router@^4.0.0 does not export browserHistory. P.s I'm relying on the react-router defined by react-router-redux. I do not explicitly define it as a dep.

Comment: @micahblu Did you manage to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @RakeshPai No. It appears that the new react-router-redux is not working correctly? The recommendations above were based on the old react-router-redux repo.

Comment: This is poorly documented but I believe this is the solution you guys are looking for: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4732#issuecomment-286289384